# adding html tags to multiple text files concatenated into one with a batch file

Tags: html, batch-file

I have a couple of dozens of html files that I want to wrap with extra code

there is a header file: "header.txt" (div starts)

multiple text files: "Text1.txt", "Text2.txt" etc etc (text body)

and a footer file "footer.txt" (div ends)

so I've come up to this code after a bit of searching on stackoverflow:

```
type header.txt >> 1.txt & type Text*.txt >> 1.txt & type footer.txt >> 1.txt
```

EDIT: edited code to mirror text

The problem is I want the headers and footers before and after EACH text file, However what the code does is write the header then ALL of the text files and in the end the footer

I'm new to creating batch files so how can I separate the operations so that each Text file would have its own extra bits.

would I have to use for loops or is there a better way to do it?

Final EDIT (for future viewers): While the files are actually Text(.txt) Files (it comes from texteditor preference) the content is HTML code. It can be whatever you want....

Regarding the concatenation into one file.
After using ascii pfl code you can just append all of the files using copy command:

```
copy *New*.txt final.html
```

Comment: The file names in the description and in your code fragment do not match! Anyway, use a `for` loop to iterate through `Text*.txt` and do the redirections in its body: `for %%F in ("Text*.txt") do (> "%%~dpnF_New%%~xF" (type "header.txt" & type "%%~fF" & type "footer.txt")`...

Comment: Thank you aschipfl !
it took me a while to understand what the code was actually doing but this is pretty cool, i thought id have to do a lot of lines for the "for" loop but this is quite elegant

Comment: Please post your comment as an answer aschipfl, ill tag it. (also dont forget the bracket at the end)

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37969795) it is! thanks for the hint concerning the missing `)`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `for` loop to iterate through your (HMTL?) files `Text*.txt` and do the redirection (`>`) in its body, like this (see the explanatory remarks):

```dos
rem // `for` loop to walk through the files:
for %%F in ("Text*.txt") do (
    rem /* one redirection to output file, so output file is opened once;
    rem    the new files will have `_New` appended to their names: */
    > "%%~dpnF_New%%~xF" (
        type "header.txt" & rem // (write header to file)
        type "%%~fF"      & rem // (write original file content)
        type "footer.txt" & rem // (write footer to file)
    )
)
```